# Error: Cask 'powershell' is not installed

Tags: macos, powershell, homebrew-cask

In VS Code on my mac, when working with PowerShell, I'm getting "Error: Cask 'PowerShell' is not installed.", after VS Code detects an old PowerShell version on my machine and fire "brew upgrade --cask PowerShell" in the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, PowerShell hadn't been installed previously using homebrew/cask.
I had to install cask first using "brew install cask" in the terminal and then install PowerShell using "brew install --cask PowerShell".